# MoveIt! compute_cartesian_path() does not compute correct joint trajectory

Tags: ros, moveit-commander, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.  When calling MoveIt! Commander's (Python) move_group.compute_cartesian_path() method, the return value is always the current joint configuration.  The code looks something like this.

```
eef_link = "gripper_palm_link"
waypoints = []
waypoints = group.get_random_pose(eef_link)
poses.append(copy.deepcopy(pose.pose))
waypoints = group.get_random_pose(eef_link)
poses.append(copy.deepcopy(pose.pose))
(plan, fraction) = group.compute_cartesian_path(waypoints, eef_step=0.01, jump_threshold=0.0, avoid_collisions=True)
```

My robot starts off in the home position which is essentially joint positions set to all zeros.  After the call to compute_cartesian_path() the resultant joint trajectory look like this:

```
header: 
  seq: 20
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: base_link
joint_names: ['arm_joint_1', 'arm_joint_2', 'arm_joint_3', 'arm_joint_4', 'arm_joint_5']
points: 
  - 
    positions: [0.001216606411158061, 0.0001137616260065144, -0.0006536926007463251, 0.0025598054398985326, 0.0007543179427678126]
    velocities: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    accelerations: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    effort: []
    time_from_start: 
      secs: 2
      nsecs: 0
```

The positions are essentially zero (i.e., the home position).  I suspect that the call to group.get_random_pose(eef_link) is returning an invalid end effector position, but I don't know why it would do that.  Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175215/moveit!-compute_cartesian_path()-does-not-compute-correct-joint-trajectory/) by [Rick C NIST](https://answers.ros.org/users/18890/rick-c-nist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-06-27**:
My guess would be that you might have screwed up in the Setup-Assistant or your urdf? Did you check the limits in the urdf?

**Comment by [Rick C NIST](https://answers.ros.org/users/18890/rick-c-nist/) on 2014-06-27**:
I am using the Kuka youbot URDF unmodified which I am assuming is correct.  The setup assistant could be the problem or maybe that I am not setting the end effector link?  One interesting data point is that if I call group.set_pose_target(pose) and then group.plan(), I get a valid trajectory from Moveit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I presume that the pose with all joints at 0 is basically the arm completely stretched out -- thus it as the limit of it's workspace. Even if the random pose is valid, there may not be a cartesian path between the points since the starting point is near the limits of the workspace. Have you tried a different starting point that is somewhat centered in the workspace of the arm?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick C NIST](https://answers.ros.org/users/18890/rick-c-nist/) on 2014-06-27**:
Joints at all 0 means the home position (i.e. all scrunched up)  Here is a picture of the home position: http://www.kuka-labs.com/NR/rdonlyres/17026737-5839-4346-9939-5D012133E9FE/0/service_youBot_Features.jpg.

I would have thought that get_random_pose() would give me a valid pose.